# Lock-free std::unordered_map<T>?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, unordered-map

I understand how you would use CAS to implement a stack or a queue. The CAS instructions would check whether the node you're grabbing has been updated at the point you go to use it. However, would one use CAS to write a lock-free std::unordered_map? There are no nodes as such- just buckets which are abstracted away from the API.

I am asking because I'd like to have a go at writing my own version.

Comment: I can recommend to have a look at facebooks folly implementation https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/AtomicHashMap.h and the talk https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10151041852263109

Comment: Note that the folly atomic map does certain optimizations which may or may not be acceptable, for example you can't remove items.

Comment: The thing in the link posted by bamboon.

Comment: There's also a lock free hashmap implementation in java based on a state machine which should be possible to port to c++ with enough effort..